# How to split file on first empty line in a portable way in shell (e.g. using sed)?

Tags: shell, sed, portability, text-manipulation, filesplitting

I want to split a file containg HTTP response into two files: one containing only HTTP headers, and one containg the body of a message.  For this I need to split a file into two on first empty line (or for UNIX tools on first line containing only CR = '`\r`' character) using a **shell script**.

How to do this in a portable way (for example using **sed**, but without GNU extensions)?  One can assume that empty line would not be first line in a file.  Empty line can got to either, none or both of files; it doesn't matter to me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$ cat test.txt
a
b
c

d
e
f
$ sed '/^$/q' test.txt 
a
b
c

$ sed '1,/^$/d' test.txt 
d
e
f
```

Change the `/^$/` to `/^\s*$/` if you expect there may be whitespace on the blank line.

Comment: It should probably be `/^\r$/`(or just in case `/^\r?$/`)

Comment: In case of use /^\r?$/ there also -r key should be used.

Answer (score 16):

You can use `csplit`:

```
echo "a
b
c

d
e
f" | csplit -s - '/^$/'
```

Or

```
csplit -s filename '/^$/'
```

(assuming the contents of "filename" are the same as the output of the echo) would create, in this case, two files named "xx00" and "xx01". The prefix can be changed from "xx" to "outfile", for example, with `-f outfile` and the number of digits in the filename could be changed to 3 with `-n 3`. You can use a more complex regex if you need to deal with Macintosh line endings.

To split a file at each empty line, you can use:

```
csplit -s filename '/^$/' '{*}'
```

The pattern `'{*}'` causes the preceding pattern to be repeated as many times as possible.

Comment: +1 you can also use it to split the file into more than 2 parts.

Comment: can you do it straight to an array in bash, rather than creating files?

Comment: @ZacThompson: I edited the answer to state this, but until it gets reviewed: you can add `'{*}'` to the end of the command above to split multiple times. e.g. `csplit filename '/^$/' '{*}'`

Comment: This doesn't work when the "empty" line contains a single CR (as specified in the question) -- csplit says "match not found"

Comment: @Chad: You can change the specification to `$'/^\r$/'`

Answer (score 4):

Given the awk script

```
BEGIN { fout="headers" }
/^$/ { fout="body" }
{ print $0 > fout }
```

`awk -f foo.awk < httpfile` will write out the two files `headers` and `body` for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the first part of your file (HTTP headers) with:

```
awk '{if($0~"^\r*$")exit;print}' myFile
```

and the second part (HTTP body) with:

```
awk '{if(body)print;if($0~"^\r*$")body=1}' myFile
```

Comment: This doesn't work; it prints out everything. Example: `wget www.google.com --save-headers --output-document - --quiet | awk '{if($0=="")exit;print}'`

Comment: @RichardBarraclough - You are correct. I edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you :) (Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.)